# CSS transform a div without affecting surrounding content

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a way to display help without the need for dialogs or popups, using CSS.

I have an image within a div, that will transition in size when the image is hovered over, displaying the help content.

I have another div below that one, that is representing the content of the page the help div will be on. Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="answers" class="answers">
        <img src="images/bullet_question.png" height="50" width="50">
    </div>
    <div class="below">will it push me down?</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    div.answers
    {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #FFF;
        z-index: 2;

    }

    div.answers:hover
    {
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        background-color: #333;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        z-index: 2;

    }

    div.below
    {
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

The question is, how to transform the answer class div, without affecting the below class div; pushing it downward. As you can see, I did some experimenting with z-index to no avail.

Comment: So you would like the div on top to not effect the div below it even though the first div is growing?

Comment: exactly that, yes. It's being pushed down at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another div to wrap your image.

**HTML**

```
<div id="answers" class="answers">
    <div class="another-div">
        <img src="images/bullet_question.png" height="50" width="50">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="below">will it push me down?</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.answers
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 2;

}

.another-div:hover
{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    position:absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    z-index: 2;

}

.below
{
    z-index: 1;
    color: red;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAQ64/)**

Comment: This didn't work for me, the below div still gets pushed down unfortunately.

Comment: make sure you have the same code as in fiddle in the answer. in your case you are manipulating class `answers`'s hover, in my case i'm manipulating new class `another-div`'s hover effect.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I just did as you said and it's working great. Thank you Zafar.

Comment: does this work because the child div, transitions into the parent? I'm happy this works, but am frustrated by my lack of understanding of it.

Comment: the `position: absolute;` property positions an element on the page by having no effect to other elements, and the element can overlay on top of other elements. the reason why you need another `div` is to keep the original position of the `.below` when the element took position absolute. i'm not sure if i could fully express my thoughts, but don't worry, you will start to understand while you acquire more experience.